# Finding largest disjoint subtrees spanning nodes

Tags: algorithms, trees

I have a taxonomy (tree) of product categories. To each leaf product category, I have assigned a shop department where the products of a given category can be found.

Now for each department, I would like to find the smallest number of the largest subtrees in the taxonomy.

For instance, in the example below leaf nodes have been assigned one of two departments $A$ and $B$.

[image: example]

The expected solution would be: $A$ has two subtrees, namely $x_2$ and $x_7$, $B$ has one subtree $x_4$.

The solution where $A$ has $x_1$ subtree is wrong because $x_1$ is the ancestor of nodes that belong to another department.

The solution where $A$ has $x_3$ and $x_7$ subtrees is wrong because we want the biggest subtrees possible.

Is it a known problem?

Is there a solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an algorithm.  Let $D(l)$ denote the department of the product category of a leaf $l$.

To find the subtree for leaf $l$ do the following.  For every leaf $l'$ such taht $D(l') \neq D(l)$, mark the node [$\text{lca}(l, l')$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor).  Now, your largest subtree is the subtree rooted in the highest unmarked node.  Call this node $\text{root}(l)$.

To compute for all leaves, clear the marks and output $\bigcup_{l \in L} \text{root}(l)$, where $L$ is the set of leaves.

---

A different (faster) algorithm: For each leaf $l$, move upwards and mark each node with $D(l)$.  If you hit a node already marked $D(l)$, you move on to the next leaf.  If you hit a node marked with a different color, delete the node.  Then your connected components should be your largest disjoint subtrees.

---

You ask if it's a *known problem*, I think that the closest you get to a known problem is the *lowest common ancestor* problem.

Comment: Thank you for using the term color, it makes the problem (and solution) more universal, like "Finding largest disjoint subtrees spanning leaves of same color"